# How to specify request params with Drive.Comments.list

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, drive

I'm able to pull back the default 20 comments with the following code when I specify a single fileId param. But I would actually like to pull back a hundred or for curiousity's sake paginate to the next 20.

From my code below, in the *getComments* function, when i specify *options* as the param to **Drive.Comments.list** it renders an error. When I specify the fileId directly it returns 20.

It should be a simple fix - I'm a bit of rookie. Any suggestions? Please and thanks!

```
function main() {
  var fileId = getFileId();
  var fileComments = getComments(fileId);
//  logObj(fileComments);
  //Logger.log(fileComments);//.items.length); // this always says 20 
//  logObj(fileComments);
  logObj(fileComments.items);
}

function getFileId() {
  return DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId(); 
}
function getComments(fileId) {
  var options = {
    'fileId': fileId,
    'pageSize': 99  
  };

  var commnts =  Drive.Comments.list(fileId);

  return commnts;
  //Logger.log(cmnts.items.length);
}
function logObj(obj){
  for (key in obj) {
    var tmp =  obj[key];
    Logger.log(key + " = " + tmp );
  }
}

function findComments(criteria){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Drive.Comments.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list) will take 2 parameters. `(fileId, {options})`. Also, the option for result limits is `maxResults` (0 to 100). Use the result `commnts.nextPageToken` with the `options.pageToken` to page through large data sets

```
function getComments(fileId) {
  var options = {
    'maxResults': 99  
  };

  var commnts =  Drive.Comments.list(fileId, options);

  return commnts;
  //Logger.log(cmnts.items.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Where do I find the relating documentation that explains that? I scoured the reference materials for this... Thanks again!

Comment: [Drive.Comments Docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/) and [Drive.Comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/comments/list). The API docs are vague at best. Doesnt really explain much, it just gives the 'what' and leaves the 'how','when','where' for us to figure out. The [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) can sometimes add a bit of help as well

Comment: Ok. Glad to know that its not me and moreso the documentation itself. 

So to clarify the second point of my question, i.e. result sets that are greater than 100 - I will need some logic like this:

`if commnts.items.length == 100 then options.pageToken = commnts.nextPageToken`

Is that right?

Comment: That is how I understood it - `length > maxResults`- and maybe a check that `nextPageToken` exist. Not sure if it would throw an error or not

Comment: Marvelous. I will update with my findings. :)

Curious why the reference websites don't open up to comments from the masses. Its unfortunate that the guidance you've provided me and what we're discovering together might not be found by a seeker.